# JSP - Unresolved custom tag

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I'm creating a custom JSP tag to generate tables from a data object.
To make the code cleaner I wanted a separate tag file for the rows but I can't seem to be able to include a custom tag in my main custom tag (sorry I know it's confusing).

For example I have:

Table.tag:

```
<%@taglib prefix="tags" uri="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%tag description="My Table">
<table>
...
  <tags:row data="${dataRow}"/>
</table>
```

Row.tag

```
<%tag description="My Row">
<tr>
  <td>...</td>
  <td>...</td>
  ...
</tr>
```

Note the import in the first file (`<%@taglib prefix="tags" uri="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags" %>`). That is generated by the editor when I try to use the `row` tag but it doesn't work. In the final page I see `<tags:row data="${dataRow}"/>` instead of the expected result.

I tried to change the import to `<%@taglib prefix="tags" tagDir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>` - which is how I use the table tag - but the result is the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where was the `row.tag` file?

Comment: @nitind in the same folder of table.tag (WEB-INF/tags)

Comment: Have you matched the case of the tag name in the file with what the .tag file uses on disk?

Comment: @nitind I have already solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue following the instructions in this answer: [JSP Tag Files in subdirectories, using a single taglib prefix. Is that possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592434/jsp-tag-files-in-subdirectories-using-a-single-taglib-prefix-is-that-possible?rq=1)

I have created a .tld file describing my custom library and then imported it in the main tag.